# Sigma-algebra: $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra; and let $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ be also a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

Because $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra containing *generator* $\mathcal{A}$. Then I am wondering whether or not $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}$?

Best!

Comment: What else should it be? Removing anything from $\mathcal A$ makes it not contain the generator. Adding anything makes it bigger than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By definition,
$$\sigma(\mathscr A)=\bigcap\{\mathscr B\,|\,\mathscr B\text{ is a $\sigma$-algebra and }\mathscr A\subseteq\mathscr B\},$$
which can be shown to be the smallest (in the sense of set inclusion) $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr A$, so that $\mathscr A\subseteq\mathscr\sigma(\mathscr A)$. But $\mathscr A$ is already a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathscr A\subseteq\mathscr A$ trivially, which implies that $\sigma(\mathscr A)\subseteq\mathscr A$.